# redirect https to http for catalog & Product pages

Tags: https, secure

we are using **https** for secure pages.

we can see **http** for **unsecure** pages - products and catalog pages.

we can see **https** for **secure** pages - My account, Login pages.

But if we manually type **https://** for home , catalog & product pages, its redirecting to **https** only. but i want to redirect to **http**

before home page, catalog & product pages are in https.

i followed this in .htaccess:

```
#Redirect your Homepage from HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

source : http://www.activo.com/redirect-https-to-http-for-any-homepage/

Than home page is working fine.

if we manually type https://example.com for home page ,its rediretcting to http://example.com. It's fine

**what i have to do for catalog & product pages**.

[image]

Comment: have you set https  for both secure & unsecure url  at magento setting?

Comment: no, i have set only for secure pages.

Comment: Please check updated image in question

Comment: it possible.. i will  do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: You may try this as well. It is specifically targeting your catalog and product page with help of editing .htaccess**

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteEngine On

    # From https to http
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalogpage/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/productpage/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]
```

And set "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to NO under System -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Options

**Method 2: Please visit following tutorial about redirecting https to http on catalog and product page:**

https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2013/06/redirecting-secure-https-non-secure-http-magento/

Comment: i tried your method 1 by replacing http://www.example.com to our site name.  . but now if we type https://product-url or  https://category-url , its redirecting to home page

Comment: @BabyinMagento Answer edited, check it out now or try method 2.

Comment: Method 2 is working. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @BabyinMagento Your welcome.

Comment: i used the above link to get an answer, but in if we go for checkout page, i am getting this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::_getCurrentSecureUrl() in in standard.php

Comment: @BabyinMagento _getCurrentSecureUrl() is not found in your Standard.php file, check and see whether you have this function found or not?

Comment: please check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95326/fatal-error-in-cart-page-after-redirecting-https-to-http i added complete standard.php file.

Comment: @BabyinMagento please check your Standard.php file, you are missing a function. And yes I also added complete standard.php file with correction on code. Please check your above link.

Comment: I have website running in https but for one url I want to run it on http instead of https when I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597395/force-specific-url-to-be-http-instead-of-https then it is creating loop. How we can resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please consider provide all pages via https
It will make your visitors feel more secure. Plus... Google ranks https site slightly higher then http sites.
Choose one protocol... Http or https. Not both.

Comment: +1 from me. Thanks for your tips.but our senior members don't agree for this for seo purpose . but you are right https is better for seo.

Comment: not only for SEO also for security for your visitors. Imagine the following setting: Your customer uses a public free wifi. A man in the middle might not be able to trace his activities on your checkout pages (https protected) but he can built a profile for every non-https page your customer visits. Using this profile the man in the middle can try to tempt your customer to visit a phishing page and hack your customers account. Use HTTPS for the entire site... no only for better SEO purposes but more important for security reasons.

Comment: sure, we will go for https.