# redirect https to http page for normal pages (cms,category,product view)

Tags: magento2

we are using https for secure pages.

we can see http for unsecure pages - **products and catalog pages.**

we can see https for secure pages - **My account, Login pages.**

But if we manually type https:// for home , catalog & product pages, its redirecting to https only. but i want to redirect to http

below is for m1.
I need for m2.
Anyone have idea how to do this in m2?

[redirect https to http for catalog & Product pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95144/redirect-https-to-http-for-catalog-product-pages)

Comment: Why would you do this? Making your shop full SSL has so many advantages concerning SEO and security. Please consider going full SSL.

Comment: use https for unsecure and secure base url, and forget it

Comment: I also wanna find a solution to this, I am using varnish on unsecure pages, but is not use if all site is redirected to https, did you find one?